# Can't convert PercentRelative Layout to Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

Basicly i created all my layouts with a library that is already deprecated (PercentRelativeLayout) everything works well except that i have this layout inside a ScrollView, and the scroll doesn't work on all devices.

I read some topics about it and seems the issue is with the Percent Library.

So i need to move on and construct the Lienar Layout example, i tried to construct my layout with the current Layout that i have but everything got buggy, the spaces between the elements are never the same as i had with the percent.

Basicly what i need is this:

[image: Pic]

The elements are top down -> toolbar -> thumbnail -> recycle view(this one just has a unique image -> details about this foto.

I have more details about it, but if i can construct this example its fine.

so my xml that i current have is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">    

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="90%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="80%"
            app:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
            android:onClick="capture"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="8%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="0%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%"/>    


        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/SpecieName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="85%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="30%"/>

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/GenreName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="genrePressed"
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="95%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="30%"/>

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/FamilyName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="familyPressed"
            android:textColor="@color/nephritis"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="60%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="105%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="30%"/>

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:text="Espécie"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="85%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="95%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            android:text="Género"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/Family"
            app:layout_widthPercent="25%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="105%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            android:text="Familia"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/specieDescription"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="90%"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="120%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"/>

        <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
            android:id="@+id/descricaoTit"
            android:text="Descrição"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            app:layout_widthPercent="30%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="115%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/plantImage"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_widthPercent="80%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="12%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="10%"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/color_cursor_white" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="10%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="62%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="0%" />

        <RelativeLayout
            app:layout_widthPercent="40%"
            app:layout_heightPercent="5%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="75%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="5%"
            android:onClick="showMap">

            <com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Helpers.OpenSansMedium
                android:id="@+id/googleMapsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView6"
                android:text="Ver no mapa" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_facebook_placeholder_for_locate_places_on_maps"
                android:tint="#F90101" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

First for solving your problem with `ScrollView` you must know `ScrollView` works if you put a `LinearLayout`  to be child of it and then cut all your `Views` inside this `LinearLayout` .

See this tree :

```
| ScrollView 
|-- LinearLayout
|---- OtherViews you want to scroll
```

Its not important what you want to put Scrolling . you must follow this way.

**EDIT :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

               // everything you want to scroll

            </LinearLayout>
         </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: isn't what i have at the moment?

Comment: i edited my answer by example code . maybe you can't use `<ScrollView>` as parent of all you layout file

Comment: the problem is the percent library, i need to cut it down, i just don't know how i can implement my layout, the current i have without the percentRelative layout, i mean with the linear

Comment: i don't  know anything about percenRelative Layout but you can do anything you want by using normal `LinearLayout` + `RelativeLayout` + `FrameLayout` , when android provide standard ways to create UI why you used another library ?

Comment: because it was really hard to me to figure out how to aling the elements as i want for diferent screan size devices, i didn't want to create multiple layouts for one activity